# Android SQLITE Query: Getting last 3 entries

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get the last 3 entries made to the database. Im using the following code but im only getting the last entry not the last 3.

```
 String query = "Select * from " + TABLE_DETAILS + " DESC limit 3;";

     SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

     Cursor cursor  = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
        cursor.close();
    } else {
    }
    db.close();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to loop with the cursor to get all result rows, e.g. instead of

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
   ...
```

loop like this

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
  System.out.println(cursor.getString(2));
}
cursor.close();
```

To change the ordering, add `ORDER BY <expression>` to your query, for example

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 3
```

Comment: The code works but im still getting the first 3 entries not the last 3

Comment: @SahilLombar Add `ORDER BY <expr>` to the query. Edited the answer.